# Finding next first record for UserID using first registered row

Tags: sql-server, self-join, data-partitioning

I'm getting a bit tied down with this and hope to find a solution. Say I have a data set like this:

```
PersonID   RowID       Reg_date     Reg_Time   Process_first_Date   Process_first_time   Process_Last_Date   Process_Last_time   End_date     End_Time
========   =========   ==========   ========   ==================   ==================   =================   =================   ==========   ========
05634222   3341278/2   01/01/2014   13:45      01/01/2014           13:45                02/01/2014          12:16               04/01/2014   18:22
05634222   3341278/6   01/01/2014   13:45      02/01/2014           12:20                03/01/2014          16:43               04/01/2014   18:22
05634222   3341278/4   01/01/2014   13:45      03/01/2014           16:48                04/01/2014          18:22               04/01/2014   18:22
08674315   8445732/1   12/01/2014   18:20      12/01/2014           18:20                13/01/2014          14:08               16/01/2014   10:12
08674315   8445732/6   12/01/2014   18:20      13/01/2014           14:12                14/01/2014          12:02               16/01/2014   10:12
08674315   8445732/8   12/01/2014   18:20      14/01/2014           12:12                16/01/2014          10:12               16/01/2014   10:12
```

Notice in one row for each `personID` the reg date/time and `process_first_time` match and in one row the process_end_date/Time Match the End Date/time. these are the entry and exit processes - first and last registration for that set of processes.

`PersonID` can have one or many processes within the first and last registration. and can have multiple sets of these first and last registrations in a certain period.

So what I would like to do is for a certain period is, using all first registrations by matching reg date and first process date and time I get all first registrations, but remembering there can be multiple first regs for one person in that period, so for example one on the 1st, one on the 8th and one on the 10th; I want only the one on the 1st if looking at a month time period.

I came up with the idea that I can put a row ID partition, partition it by `PersonID` and order it by reg date and this gave me what I want, in other words for data set above I would get:

```
PersonID  Row_partition   RowID       Reg_date     Reg_Time   Process_first_Date   Process_first_time   Process_Last_Date   Process_Last_time   End_date     End_Time
========  =============   =========   ==========   ========   ==================   ==================   =================   =================   ==========   ========
05634222  1               3341278/2   01/01/2014   13:45      01/01/2014           13:45                02/01/2014          12:16               04/01/2014   18:22
08674315  1               8445732/1   12/01/2014   18:20      12/01/2014           18:20                13/01/2014          14:08               16/01/2014   10:12
```

Now that I have first reg of each PersonID I want to use this in a sub-query or inline view and this is where I am getting stuck. Not sure how I can do this.

So I have query as below to give me this first reg:

```
   SELECT *
FROM(
select PersonID  
,Row_partition SEQ   
,RowID       
,Reg_date     
,Reg_Time   
,Process_first_Date   
,Process_first_time   
,Process_Last_Date   
,Process_Last_time   
,End_date     
,End_Time
FROM PERSON INNER JOIN PROCESS_ACTIVITY ON (PERSON.PERSON_KEY=PROCESS_ACTIVITY.PERSON_KEY)
RIGHT OUTER JOIN TIME  PROCESS_START ON (PROCESS_START.DATE_KEY=PROCESS_ACTIVITY.PROCESS_START_DATE_KEY)
RIGHT OUTER JOIN TIME  PROCESS_END ON (PROCESS_END.DATE_KEY=PROCESS_ACTIVITY.PROCESS_END_DATE_KEY)
RIGHT OUTER JOIN TIME  REGDATE ON (REGDATE.DATEKEY=PROCESS_ACTIVITY.REG_DATE_KEY)
RIGHT OUTER JOIN TIME  ENDDATE ON (ENDDATE.DATEKEY=PROCESS_ACTIVITY.END_DATE_KEY)
RIGHT OUTER JOIN DEPT ON (DEPT.DEP_KEY=PROCESS_ACTIVITY.FCE_DEP_KEY)
INNER JOIN STAY ON (STAY_KEY=PROCESS_ACTIVITY.FCE_STAY_KEY)
RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.LEAVECONDIT ON (dbo.LEAVECONDIT.D_PAC_LEAVECONDIT_KEY=PROCESS_ACTIVITY.LEAVECONDIT_KEY)

WHERE REGDATE.FULLDATE  BETWEEN  '20140101'  AND  '20141231'
AND DEPT.DEPT_DESC  In  ( 'DEPT1','DEPT2','DEPT3','DEPT4','DEPT5','DEPT6','DEPT7','DEPT8','DEPT9')
AND dbo.LEAVECONDIT.LEAVE_CODE IN ('18','52','16','42','12','22','40','53','48')
AND REGDATE.FULLDATE = PROCESS_START.FULLDATE
AND convert(varchar(5),PROCESS_ACTIVITY.REG_TIME, 108) = convert(varchar(5),PROCESS_ACTIVITY.PROCESS_FIRST_TIME, 108)
)B
WHERE B.SEQ = 1
```

And I am wondering if I can use this to then join to effectively the same data set and look for next registrations after the first ones for the period?

hope that is clear if not I can try and explain further.

Andrew

EDIT: for the last output, if the 2 person Id's had a next registration on the 08/01/2014 and 15/01/2014 respectively then the output would be like this:

```
    PersonID  RowID       Reg_date     Reg_Time   Process_first_Date   Process_first_time   Process_Last_Date   Process_Last_time   End_date     End_Time
    ========  =========   ==========   ========   ==================   ==================   =================   =================   ==========   ========
    05634222  3368432/5   08/01/2014   16:00      08/01/2014           16:00                09/01/2014          18:06               10/01/2014   13:04
    08674315  8653358/1   15/01/2014   12:20      15/01/2014           12:20                18/01/2014          14:14               19/01/2014   10:12
```

Comment: can you include what the last result should look like? with outer apply you can search for the next record.

Comment: @mxix I've include what the output should be based on 2 more first registrations, one for each personID

Comment: Could you include the output based on the first registrations, or include those to the original data. what row are you trying to join to what?

Comment: what version of Sql server?

Comment: @mxix The output for first registrations is in my question - the first set of two rows. The next set of two rows is the data I would like to return based on the first two rows in the first section. These are first registrations in the period, and then using these I want to look for the next registration after the first for that personID. So in one month say I would look for row with earliest reg date for a particular PersonID, then using that data look in the complete data set for the next registration for that personID after the first one.

Comment: @Rikalous Sql Server express 2008 R2 but linked to a SQL Server 2005 DB where the data is, so 2008 stuff probably won't work on this session.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right I think what you are trying to achieve can be done via CTE, like

```
;WITH cte AS(
select PersonID,
,Row_partition SEQ 
...
FROM PERSON INNER JOIN PROCESS_ACTIVITY ON ...
)
Select * from cte where Seq = 1
Union All
Select * from cte where Seq = 2
```

or

```
;WITH cte AS(
select PersonID,
,Row_partition SEQ 
...
FROM PERSON INNER JOIN PROCESS_ACTIVITY ON ...
)
Select * from cte c1
JOIN cte c2 on c1.PersonID = c2.PersonID AND c1.SEQ = 1 AND c2.SEQ = 2
```

Comment: That might be what I need - i'll have a look at it but really don't understand this cte much so will do a bit of reading about it.